# Fragment$add() causes slow performance for recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

So, let's say I have recyclerview and it has some elements. Recyclerview is placed in FragmentA which is added with method `replace`. When clicking on recyclerview item FragmentB get opened with method `add`. There is another recyclerview in FragmentB that has **the same** adapter and **the same** parameters(fixed size, linearlayoutmanager, etc.) as recyclerview in FragmentA.
FragmentA and FragmentB have **the same** xml

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar>
            <TextView />
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBarLayout>

            <SwipeRefreshLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            </SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The question is why recyclerview placed in FragmentA is scrolling very smoothly and recyclerview placed in FragmentB isn't scrolling smoothly enough, it seems like scrolling effect has low fps because of bad performance.

*If I open FragmentB with method `replace` instead of `add` then scrolling effect becomes very smooth...*

I am not sure whether I should put fragments code here because there is no specific difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

Using `add` puts your FragmentB on top of FragmentA, so it still exists and is drawing below. When you use `replace`, FragmentA gets detached and its view is destroyed.

If you're using the same adapter in both fragments, consider creating a  [RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool.html) in your activitys `onCreate()`, then sharing it between recyclers so either fragment can fetch existing ViewHolders instead of recreating them when attached:

**In fragments onCreateView():**

```
RecyclerView recycler = findViewById(...);
recycler.setRecycledViewPool(((YourActivity)getActivity()).getSharedRecycledViewPool());
```